# CPU and Memory usage during Ant/Maven/Gradle build process

Tags: maven, memory, build, task, cpu

Trying find way to monitor CPU and Memory usage during Java build process. I want to compare resource consumption during Ant/Maven/Gradle build tasks. Want to achieve this on my local machine. Have seen java profiler but it doesn't cooperate with build tasks ;/.

Comment: What do you need to know? Would a hprof or flight recorder file do?

Comment: For example when I run compile or install - Maven tasks then I  want to see Cpu level  from start to finish the process, same for memory. JDK profiler shows me that but I can't see when process starts and finish

Comment: Look into Java Flight Recorder to see if it can provide the information you need.